# php explode() not working when receiving string from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, smarty, explode

I'm getting data values from javascript and append a smarty template with parameters. With a smarty function i want to explode the string with php.

The HTML:

```
 <div class="item-wrapper pre_element_block draggable-column ui-widget-content" data-floated_width="col-md-12" data-width_info="12">
```

This is the javascript:

```
function row_droppable (droppableContainer) {
    $(droppableContainer).on('drop',function(event,ui){
        if(ui.draggable.hasClass('draggable-column')) {
            id = get_random_string();
            var grid = ui.draggable.attr("data-width_info");
            gridRow = $(`{include file=$oPlugin->cAdminmenuPfad|cat:'templates/ns.cs.grid_row.tpl' grid='` + grid + `' idUnique='`+id+`'}`).appendTo(droppableContainer);
        }
    });  
}
```

In

> templates/ns.cs.grid_row.tpl

i call:

```
    {js_string_convert string=$grid}
```

This is my php / smarty function:

```
$smarty->register_function("js_string_convert", "js_string_convert");

function js_string_convert($params,$smarty) {
    if(!empty($params['string'])) {
        $colArr = explode("_", $params['string']);
        $smarty->assign('colArr',$colArr);
    }
}
```

When i dump the data `$params['string']` in php it puts out:

```
 string(12) "4_4_4"
```

So i try to explode the string:

```
$colArr = explode("_", $params['string']);
```

When i dump `$colArr` it puts out:

```
array(1) {
    [0] => string(12) "4_4_4"
}
```

This is driving me crazy. Does it have something to do with receiving the string from javascript?

**UPDATE:**
The length of the dumped string depends on how long the variable in my javascript is. The string(12) is because the variable `grid` is so long. When i change `grid` to `adasdasdasdasdasdasd` the string is string(33) e.g.

Comment: Does `strpos($params['string'],"_")` return false?

Comment: Yes, it returns false.

Comment: An encoding issue perhaps? The underscore  is not an underscore...

Comment: Try doing a [`ord`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) of each character in the string and make sure the underscores match the actual `ord("_")` value.

Comment: The underscore comes from html data-width="4_4_4". In jQuery i get this value via .attr('data-width') and append an smarty template with this value.

Comment: Did you type or copy-paste the `string(12) "4_4_4"`? Note that it says the string is 12 characters long, so there's quite obviously something fishy going on. Try to copy the original attribute from your HTML and run it through `hexdump` to see what it is exactly.

Comment: hmmm
How could this string be 12 chars long?!

Comment: Did you try to trim the string before exploding ?

Comment: @PascalCloverfield you have some hidden characters there that you need to cleanup first. It might be character encoding issue on the data. Can you find out what character  encoding the data has?

Comment: The data is ASCII

Comment: Can you paste your html/js code here?

Comment: Could <meta charset="windows-1252" /> has something to do with it?

Comment: Can you add `console.log(ui.draggable.attr("data-width_info").replace(/(.)/g,function(a) { return a.codePointAt(0).toString(16)+" "; }))` in your JS?

Comment: I get something like console.log(grid.replaceâ€Œâ€‹(/(.)/g ...Is this the root of evil?

Comment: I copied the code to txt file now and than back to javascript. Now the console just say 4_4_4 and the html puts out console.log(grid.replace(/(.â€Œâ€‹) ...

Comment: Not sure where you get that `â€Œâ€‹` from... It should be `replace(/(.)/g,function...`

Answer (score 0):

`var_dump("4_4_4")` should return string(**5**) "4_4_4", not string(**12**) as in your case. Possible you have unprintable symbols in your string or issues with charset encoding.

You can check your string by this:

```
var_dump( preg_match('/^\d+\_\d+\_\d+$/', $params['string']) );
```

If you will receive `false`, then you have not only `[DIGIT][UNDERSCORE][DIGIT][UNDERSCORE][DIGIT]` in your string (but it's obvious).

You can try to find string with three positive integer numbers and two underscore by this:

```
preg_match('/\d+\_\d+\_\d+/', $params['string'], $tmp);
```

If $tmp[0] will be not empty, than you can explode $tmp[0] instead of the original string.

Or you can try to use this regex for the extracting numbers:

```
preg_match('/(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+)/u', $params['string'], $tmp);
```

In `$tmp[1]`, `$tmp[2]` and `$tmp[3]` can be your three numbers.